Has the U.S. Defense Department ever lost a designation lawsuit?
Chinese drone giant DJI sued the  U.S. Defense Department (DOD) for being designated a "Chinese military company".
Has the DOD ever lost a lawsuit involving such a designation?
The VOA story also has this bit:

In May, lidar manufacturer Hesai Group ZN80y.F filed a suit challenging the Pentagon's Chinese military designation for the company. On Wednesday, the Pentagon removed Hesai from the list but said it will immediately relist the China-based firm on national security grounds.

It's unclear to me if the DOD actually lost that lawsuit or any other.
Another (Reuters) story says:

The Justice Department said late Wednesday in a court filing the Pentagon had delisted Hesai on the basis of the original grounds and now plans to relist the Chinese company "based on the latest information available."

So it doesn't sound like a loss, although perhaps that case is still ongoing.

Also. China's AMEC sues U.S. defence department over 'military company' label.

Two sources were used for the designation of "Chinese military companies": Section 1237 of the National Defense Appropriations Act of 1999 and Section 1260H of the National Defense Appropriations Act of 2021.
Section 1237 was implemented by Executive Order 13959 signed by President Trump on November 12, 2020, and expanded by Executive Order 14032 signed by President Biden on June 3, 2021.
On January 12, 2021, Xiaomi Corporation was added to the 1237 list. Subsequently, Xiaomi sued the Defense Department to be removed from the list. In Xiaomi Corp. v. Dep't of Def., the court found the DOD designation to be "deeply flawed" and a preliminary injunction was issued on March 12, 2021. Xiaomi does not appear on the 1260H list. Count that as a loss for the DOD.
While Hesai Technology Co. sued the DOD, their motion was denied and the company is on the 1260H list.
Suits by Advanced Micro-Fabrication Equipment Inc. and Shenzhen DJI Innovation Technology Co., Ltd., LTD. are in the preliminary stages and have not been heard by the DC District Court. Both companies remain on the 1260H list.
